# Simple save data to db in Craft CMS

Tags: database

I am new to Craft CMS.  Please tell me about how can I save data into database in Craft?

I have searched a lot of results about my query but nothing give advantage to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to read about the [Yii Query Builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder)

```
craft()->db->createCommand()
    ->insert('mytablename', array(
        'field1'    => 'foo',
        'field2'    => 'bar'
    ));
```

Or you can use [Active Records](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar) in [Craft](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/records)

```
$record = new Record();
$record->field1 = 'foo';
$record->field2 = 'bar';
$record->save();
```

Or you can use Craft Elements (entries/categories/tags)

```
$entry = new EntryModel();
$attributes = [
   'section'   => $yourSectionId,
   'entryType' => $yourEntryTypeId,
   'field1'    => 'foo',
   'field2'    => 'bar'
];
$entry->getContent()->setAttributes($attributes);
craft()->entries()->saveEntry($entry);
```

Comment: Let me know if you got it

Comment: ok i will notify

Answer (score 1):

there should be execute() fn at the last to execute the sql query

```
craft()->db->createCommand()
->insert('mytablename', array(
    'field1'    => 'foo',
    'field2'    => 'bar'
))
->execute();
```